# Android Fragment error on Orientation Change

Tags: android, static, android-fragments, screen-orientation

I know there are similar Questions here, but I need to know what to do in my use case.
I got the error

`make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public`

This is because my `inner Fragment Class` needs to be `static` and return an instance. I've my screen handling in the `setScreens() method`, which breaks when I set it to static, which I've to do, if I want to call it from the static Fragment.

Because I am using `GlobalState` which extends the Application, for saving my selection and it shows error when accessing `R.id.`

I need this, because I need to access the data in diverse Classes!

This is an excerpt from the main class, I later need to do it with 4 Fragments.

```
//imports ... 
public class MainScreen extends FragmentActivity{

    GlobalState globalState;
    String statute,section;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        GlobalState globalState = (GlobalState)getApplication();

        try {
            statute = globalState.getStatute();
            section = globalState.getSection();

        }catch (NullPointerException e){}

         setScreens();
    }

     public void setScreens(){
             GlobalState globalState = (GlobalState)getApplication();
             try {
                 statute = globalState.getStatute();
                 section = globalState.getSection();
             }catch (NullPointerException e){e.printStackTrace();}

            int i = getLowestSelection();

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            //setting up for Landscape
            //if (findViewById(R.id.fragtwo) != null) ...

            //setting up for portrait

            if (findViewById(R.id.fragone) != null) {

                    if (i == 0){
                        StatuteScreen statuteScreenFragment = new StatuteScreen(); //External Class, no problem
                        transaction.replace(R.id.fragone,statuteScreenFragment);
                    }
                    else if (i == 1){
                        SectionsScreen sectionsScreenFragment = new SectionsScreen();//Inner Class throws the error
                        transaction.replace(R.id.fragone,sectionsScreenFragment);
                    }
            }           
         transaction.addToBackStack(null);
         transaction.commit();
    }

     public class SectionsScreen extends Fragment{

        String title;
        ArrayList<DetailData> dataList;
        ListView listView;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sections,container,false);

            listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lvSections);

            DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(getActivity());

            globalState = (GlobalState)getActivity(). getApplication();

            try {
                title = globalState.getStatute();
            } catch (NullPointerException e){};

            if(title != null){
                dataList = dataBaseHelper.getDetailsNames(title);

                dataBaseHelper.close();
                listView.setAdapter(new SectionsAdapter(getActivity(),dataList));
                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                        globalState.setSection(dataList.get(i).getAbsch());
                        setScreens();
                    }
                });
            }
            return  view;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get this to work, so it doesn't crash on orientation change?
Can I get `Globalstate` and `R.id` from static method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing this all wrong.

I stongly suggest you take the time to read the [docs on Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), especially the section "Communicating with the Activity". The way you are using the Application class makes no sense.

> make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public

I don't see an empty public constructor... and without declaring the inner class as static, it will hold a reference to it's Activity and cause leaks and other issues.

You can avoid this whole thing by refactoring `SectionsScreen` into it's own file, or using the proper callback patterns.

Comment: ok thx for the feedback. I had the Fragments in their own files at first. But i need them all to call the setScreens method, and thought using inner classes is the way to go. Wasn't sure if i can implement callbacks from all 4 fragments in the Main Activity.

Comment: Read the documentation (linked above) and you will find the proper way to do all of this.

Comment: Will do ty. I guess i will be implementing callback interfaces of all fragments then. I thought this was cleaner if i had it all in one place. But makes sense i guess.

Comment: ok, refactored and its working thx. Just thought there was a way with inner classes

Comment: @M4tchB0X3r Your welcome. Nore: You can use an inner class, it just needs to be static. This issue was your callback implementation (GlobalState/setScreens).